# LongListSelector: Dynamic GridCellSize

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a LongListSelector and I have the following ViewModel

```
ViewModel: 
    List<ListData>

ListData:
    Text
    Image
```

I need the cell size dynamic depending on an ListData.

If Text is absent, I'll hide the image and make the GridCellSize = 50. If Image is present, the GridCellSize should be 250,250;

It'll look like this:

```
 +---------+   +---------+
 |  Text   |   |  Text   |
 +---------+   +---------+
 +---------+   +---------+
 |  Text   |   |  Text   |
 +---------+   +---------+
 +---------+   +---------+
 |         |   |         |
 |         |   |         |
 |  Image  |   |  Image  |
 |         |   |         |
 |         |   |         |
 +---------+   +---------+
 +---------+   +---------+
 |         |   |         |
 |         |   |         |
 |  Image  |   |  Image  |
 |         |   |         |
 |         |   |         |
 +---------+   +---------+
```

I tried changing the GridCellSize using a convertor but it seems the GridCellSize needs to be constant for a LongListSelector and applies to all the elements.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

in one line i can say that you can bind your grid Height and Width property to some double properties and can handle it on your logic..but i have also a some code for your logic.hope it helps you..

so first made a class of **ListData** in which i have made some properties which is going to use by item of **longlistSelector** ..here is the class..

```
 public class ListData
{


    public double height { get; set; }
    public double width { get; set; }

    public string text { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public Visibility isTextVisible { get; set; }
    public Visibility isImageVisible { get; set; }

}
```

now i have created a **ObservableCollection** with which your **LongListSelector itemsSource** property is going to be binded..

```
  public ObservableCollection<ListData> ListOfData { get; set; }
```

now i have filled this collection with data..here data is your **ListData** class Objects with Diffrent Values of properties that is going to reflect in your **LongListSelector Item**..i have filled it in my mainpage constructor..

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListOfData = new ObservableCollection<ListData>();
        ListData sd = new ListData();
        sd.ImagePath = "/Assets/1.jpg";
        sd.text = "";
        sd.isTextVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
        sd.isImageVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        sd.height = 250;
        sd.width = 250;

        ListData sd1 = new ListData();
        sd1.ImagePath = "/Assets/1.jpg";
        sd1.text = "afhjkahfjkahjkghadgjkgjkv";
        sd1.isTextVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        sd1.isImageVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
        sd1.height = 50;
        sd1.width = 50;

        ListOfData.Add(sd);
        ListOfData.Add(sd1);
        ListOfData.Add(sd);
        ListOfData.Add(sd1);
        ListOfData.Add(sd);
        ListOfData.Add(sd1);
        ListOfData.Add(sd);
        ListOfData.Add(sd1);

        this.DataContext = this;

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }
```

now everything is ready..I have Data and DataContext of the Page is set..so waht's remaining is your xaml page in which LingListSelector is defined..here i have binded every propety ..just sake of your convinience..

```
 <phone:LongListSelector Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfData}">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="{Binding height}" Width="{Binding width}" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=text}" Visibility="{Binding isTextVisible}"/>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" Visibility="{Binding isImageVisible}"  />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
```

here..all things are being done..it requires your logic now..hope it helps you..

Comment: The solution works for LayoutMode="List" but if I set the LayoutMode="Grid", it crashes with Exception 'System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.'

Comment: Appreciate it. 
BTW looks like it's a bug in the framework itself
[Bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/782748/longlistselector-layoutmode-grid-throws-exception-if-gridcellsize-is-not-set-windows-phone-8-sdk)

Comment: look when you are setting your layout to be grid..actually longlistselector is expected to implemente like jumpliststyle..its data must be defined on the basis of that..so just check this sample .."http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/06/18/implementing-longlistselector-as-jumplists-in-windows-phone-8-alphabetical-list.aspx"..hope it helps in your case..